# AWS Lambda alternates between success and timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am currently running a function on aws lambda. The strange thing is, after each successful execution, it will result in a time out if I run it again. And after each time out runs, when I run the test again, it became successful.

At times when the function resulted in time out, lambda didn't seem to do anything. I put a few console.log in my function and none of them got printed.

My function can usually be finished in around 30 seconds, so timing out a 60 seconds period seems rather strange to me.

Does anyone know what could have happened?

Error messages:
[image]

My log:
[image]

This is the code for my function:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-lambda');
const test1 = require("./test1.js");
const test2 = require("./test2.js")

exports.handler = async function(event, context) {

    let browser = await puppeteer.getBrowser({headless: true});

    //run test

    let tests = [test1.test, test2.test];

    //run all test cases in parallel
    let result = await Promise.all(tests.map(test => test(browser)));

    //output logs of each test case
    for (let log of result) {
        console.log(log);
    }

    await browser.close();
    console.log("All tests finish running");
}
```

Comment: Does your code load or initialize any resources outside of the Lambda function itself? I'm thinking of what your entire source code and all of its dependencies have to statically load or initialize *before* the Lambda function itself can be executed.

Comment: Do you see success and timeouts in the same logstreams or in different ones?

Comment: @jarmod I used puppeteer-lambda in my source code. Do you think it's causing the problem?

Comment: @Dunedan I see success and timeouts in different log streams when I run manual testings.However, when I use Cloudwatch scheduler to trigger it, the test first timeouts, then automatically reruns and gives a successful run.

Comment: Even when successful (as worm start) it takes 32 seconds, so it is plausible that a cold star it takes more than 60 seconds. Try to schedule it at one minute to see how it works. My take is a case of cold start: https://theburningmonk.com/2017/06/aws-lambda-compare-coldstart-time-with-different-languages-memory-and-code-sizes/

Comment: @blueCat I tried scheduling it at one minute interval and the pattern still exists. And the successful run always happens before the time out one, so it's probably not due to cold start

Comment: The puppeteer-lambda package suggests a min Lambda RAM size of 384 MB so presumably you've configured at least that. Have you added console.log statements before and after every require/import and any other static initialization to see if that gives you additional clues. It would be good to understand what, if anything, is actually logged during the run that times out.

Comment: @lmc crank up the memory (which simultaneously increases the available CPU cycles) and increase the timeout to the max.  Until you do that, you're guessing.

Comment: Any external dependencies? It seems like the successful run "lock" some resource and the next run fails.  If you increase memory and time to max, the seconds run still fails?

Comment: I increase both my time and memory to max and it still times out. However, by adding additional logging message, I figured it always stops right before `let browser = await puppeteer.getBrowser({headless: true});`. I think puppeteer-lambda is probably the reason, but I am not sure why

Comment: Does `puppeteer-lambda` rely on some hardware-specific configuration (not familiar with it)? I once used an open-source library that was compiled to run on specific hardware specs. Lambda servers are ephemeral, so you get a different server at each execution. Sometimes it matched the specs expected by the library, sometimes it didn't. Took me a week to find out and finally fix the library compilation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are known issues with using puppeteer-lambda to open a browser, close it then open it again.

What you are seeing is the second invocation of your Lambda failing because it is being run in the same container as the first 'successful' invocation.

Then why would the third try work? Because the second invocation of the Lambda is killed due to timeout, probably along with whatever temp info that is causing the error in the first place.

You could try instantiating the browser outside of the call handler and just never closing it, so it is available for the next time you run the tests. I don't know if there will be any time out issues with this though.

Answer (score 0):

As a followup:

One way I found successful is like what @K Mo suggested -- never close the browser. However, my test performs log in to certain websites, and reusing the same browser results in inconsistent behavior since log in is required for the first run but not for the second run.

What I eventually did is to use puppeteer instead of puppeteer-lambda. I used a plugin from https://github.com/Tchangang/puppeteer-lambda-launcher to help me configure and download chrome from a s3 bucket.

Thank everyone in the comment for the help! My test is now running well!